# Answer Box Not Showing

Tags: support, answers

Why is it that whenever I decide to answer some question on Stack, some of the questions do not pop answer box for me to contribute in the solution? Do I need reputations even to answer a question!!

Comment: It shows [duplicate]

Comment: That means it's closed. You can't answer a closed question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/117120/prerequisites-for-griffiths-electrodynamics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was closed as a duplicate of another question by 5 users. Duplicate questions are closed questions, and you can't answer a closed question.

See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions